# How to map one album in Photos?

Tags: photos, maps

In Photos, I can press the 'Places' button and see a map with all my photos.

How do I get the map to show the photos of only one album?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Photos for Mac OS:

1. Visit the album you'd like a Places map for.
2. Click **Show as memory** at the top of the main window (located directly under the name of the album).
3. Scroll down, and you'll see a Places map with only the photos of the active album.

Comment: I can't seem to see this in macOS Ventura. Do you know if it has been removed? Or do you have a screenshot that shows more clearly where it located, please? Thanks.